# How do I allow VS Code to use Local WP’s PHP with Open SSL enabled?

Tags: php, wordpress, openssl, composer-php, localhost

I'm trying to set up a local WordPress back-end/NextJS front-end website using [these instructions](https://webdevstudios.github.io/nextjs-wordpress-starter/docs/backend).

Ensuring I have the dependencies installed, I follow the instructions to [install Composer](https://getcomposer.org/download/), but when running `php composer-setup.php` I receive:

```
Some settings on your machine make Composer unable to work properly.
Make sure that you fix the issues listed below and run this script again:

The openssl extension is missing, which means that secure HTTPS transfers are impossible.
If possible you should enable it or recompile php with --with-openssl
```

My VS Code has PHP located:

```
"php.validate.executablePath": "C:/Users/Steve/AppData/Local/Programs/Local/resources/extraResources/lightning-services/php-8.1.9+8/bin/win64/php.exe"
```

& checking `C:\Users\Steve\AppData\Local\Programs\Local\resources\extraResources\lightning-services\php-8.1.9+8\conf\php.ini`: I see:

`extension=php_openssl.dll`

is uncommented.

Checking `http://mysite-nextjs.local/local-phpinfo.php` I see:

```
PHP Version 8.1.9
SSL Version OpenSSL/1.1.1q
```

- I'm assuming this site uses PHP 8.1.9 from `C:/Users/Steve/AppData/Local/Programs/Local/resources/extraResources/lightning-services/php-8.1.9+8/bin/win64/php.exe` listed above,
- and I know `openssl.conf` lives at `C:\Users\Steve\AppData\Local\Programs\Local\resources\extraResources\lightning-services\php-8.1.9+8\bin\win64\extras\ssl\openssl.cnf`.
- Because VS Code is using this same `php.exe`, would it be safe to assume it knows where OpenSSL is?
- I did find `C:\Users\Steve\AppData\Local\Programs\Local\resources\extraResources\lightning-services\php-8.1.9+8\bin\win64\php.ini-development` had `;extension=openssl`, uncommenting it did not resolve the error,
- and `C:\Users\Steve\Local Sites\mysite-nextjs\conf\php\php.ini.ibs` already had `extension=php_openssl.dll` uncommented.

**How do I allow VS Code to use Local WP's PHP with Open SSL enabled**?

Using `Local WP 6.7.2` on Windows 11 64-bit.

Comment: Please share more details. How is your problem related to Wordpress or localhost? What have you tried to resolve it? Are you sure that the extension got enabled properly?

Comment: [This answer](https://superuser.com/a/1051443/34252) solved it for me.